# WordPress - How to assign a post a *main* category

Tags: wordpress, post, categories

Let's say I have a (fictious) post: 'Google and Tesla join to produce smart electric cars'

I want to classify it in multiple categories: 'IT', 'Automotive', 'Environment', 'Engineering'

But I want to make one of these categories the main one, let's say 'Automotive' in this case.

How can I tell WordPress that 'Automotive' is the main category and I want the URL to be something like 'http://www.mysite.com/automotive/google-and-tesla-join-to-produce-smart-electric-car'?

Your help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm.. I do not think you can do that. You can have child categories, but what you are asking (?) is to have separate parent categories and then assign one as the main one.

You could set Automotive as the category, and the remaining (Environment, Engineering) as tags, that would give you the url you want. Hope it helps.